# Set Column Attribute to be Date and Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on MySql and I have to set the time-stamp of the one of the field of my column to be 4 days ahead from current time-stamp. I created the triggers for the same.

My timestamp fields are Insert_Time and Bid_Time with Default value set as Current_Timestamp.

```
My Trigger Query: 
CREATE TRIGGER setDefaultDate BEFORE INSERT ON product FOR EACH ROW SET New.Bid_Time = ADDDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

I tried inserting the rows into table but trigger seems not working. In both the fields I can see the current timestamp only.[image]

```
My Insert Query:
insert into test.product (ITEM_NAME,ITEM_DESC,Item_Price, ITEM_QTY,SELLER_FIRSTNAME, SELLER_LASTNAME,EMAIL,SELLER_USERNAME,CATEGORY,GROUP_NAME,Bid,COND ) values ('J.K Rowling','HARRYPOTTER AND MYSTERY ','60','10','sahil','kaw', 'sahil1.kaw@gmail.com', 'sahraw','BOOKS','FICTION','1','NEW');
```

Is it because I am not providing the timestamp value while inserting.

Please find the screen-print attached for the schema of the tables.

Comment: Your trigger is correct.  It should be setting the value.

Comment: Do I need to set the update clause in the timestamp while declaring the column in the table

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly speculation, but I'm pretty sure the problem is the fact that `bid_time` has a default value of `timestamp`.  Such columns are automatically initialized.

Unfortunately, the copious [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) on the subject does not seem to address triggers.  However, I could easily imagine that the automatic value over-rides the trigger.

Comment: What can I set the default value then? I dont think that mysql would allow me to create a timestamp column without specifying default value. My requirement is to set the column of the product table 4 days from todays date i.e to 10th Oct 2016

Comment: @maverick . . . If you have a trigger, then set the value there.  In other words, you don't need a default value if you are using a trigger to set the value.